# LINQ - count from select with join with no group by

Tags: linq

Linq is brand new to me so I apologize if this is really stupid.

I am trying to get the count from a multi-table join with where clause, without group by.  I've seen examples of group by and will resort to that if need be, but I am wondering if there is a way to avoid it.  Is sql my query would look something like this;

```sql
 SELECT Count(*)
FROM   plans p
       JOIN organizations o
         ON p.org_id = o.org_id
            AND o.deleted IS NULL
       JOIN orgdata od
         ON od.org_id = o.org_id
            AND od.active = 1
       JOIN orgsys os
         ON os.sys_id = od.sys_id
            AND os.deleted IS NULL
WHERE  p.deleted IS NULL
       AND os.name NOT IN ( 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz' )
```

What's the best way to get this?

Comment: Linq to? (entities/sql). What navigation properties have you got? You probably don't need join statements in linq.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to call `Count()`. You're *only* counting the number of results. So something like:

```
var names = new[] { "xxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz" };
var query = from plan in db.Plans
            where plan.Deleted == null
            join organization in db.Organizations
              on plan.OrganizationId equals organization.OrganizationId
            where organization.Deleted == null
            join orgData in db.OrganizationData
              on organization.OrganizationId equals orgData.OrganizationId
            where orgData.Active == 1
            join os on db.OrganizationSystems
              on orgData.SystemId equals os.SystemId
            where os.Deleted == null &&
                  !names.Contains(os.Name)
            select 1; // It doesn't matter what you select here
 var count = query.Count();
```